# Android Lint saying possible NullPointerException for ActionBar

Tags: java, android

My Main Activity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }
}
```

I use the following theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

The actionbar works and looks fine, but Android Lint say stuff like:
     `Method invocation '((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show()' at line X may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'`

Why is it saying this? Is this just a bug in Android Lint or is it actually possible to (sometimes) get nullpointer exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `assert getSupportActionBar() != null;` in your Code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
```

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to mark this post as resolved if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using windowActionBar as false in style, android studio assumes that your app doesnt have an action bar. That's why you get this warning. Since you have already setup your toolbar as the actionbar, it wont give any problems. You may enclose that in a try catch block if you want.

Comment: Thanks, was just wondering if it ever could throw an exception.

Comment: If you dont set toolbar as actionBar it will throw and exception.